# How to deduce angle an image was rotated through?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image that was rotated to an unknown angle, and I don't have the original image. How I determine the angle of rotation with matlab commands?

I need to rotate the image back with this angle to reach the original image.

Comment: Without the original image, how will you recognise the correct un-rotation when you find it ?

Comment: BTW, the tag has been broken up.  "image processing" not "image" "processing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) mentions in his comment, it is difficult to give an answer when it is unclear how you can recognize that the image is rotated, or what would make you decide that the rotation has properly been corrected.

In other words, you will first have to find a way to determine the rotation angle by analyzing the image with respect to specific features that inform you about a potential rotation. For example, if your image contains a face, you'd do face detection (for which there is plenty of code on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) and then rotate so that the eyes are up and the mouth down. If your image contains lines that should be vertical and/or horizontal in an un-rotated image, you can apply a [Hough-transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html) to your image and find the most likely angle of rotation using [houghpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/houghpeaks.html).

Finally, to rotate your image, you can use [imrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imrotate.html).

Comment: excuse me i dont know how accept it? it was accepted,only in the final step i dont know how extract the angle rotation. please help me again? thank you very much jonas.

Comment: @mohammad: In order to accept an answer officially, you can click the checkmark next to the question. As to extracting the angle: If you're using the Hough-transform, the y-axis in the result is the orientation of the line. The most common orientation results in the highest value in the Hough-transform result. Thus, if you identify the coordinates of highest value in the Hough-transform result, the y-value is the rotation angle.

Comment: @mohammad: Following the link in my profile allows you to get in contact with me. However, if you have specific questions, it is best to create new questions on this site, where there are many other excellent programmers who can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Without examples or a more detailed description, it's hard to give good advice.  But generally, this can be done for some types of images.

For example, suppose the image shows buildings, poles, furniture or something that should have vertical edges. Run an edge detector, then take a Fourier transform.  There should be peaks, or some visible pattern in the power spectrum, along the Y axis for an unrotated image.  The power spectrum rotates the same way as the image.  If you can devise an algorithm to find the spectral features that indicate vertical edges, you can measure its angle w.r.t. the origin (zero frequency).  That is the angle of image rotation.

But  you will have to distinguish that particular feature from all other image features that show in the power spectrum.  Have fun with that - this is the kind of detail that will take most of your creativity and time.